# How to do Cross Validation or Hold-Out Validation (Keras-like) with Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, cross-validation

I want to do Cross Validation or Hold-Out Validation with the API that I have mentioned in the title.I have already read all the similar questions but I have not found the solution.

I want to simulate something like validation_split of Keras, so before testing, I want to save the best model with best performance on validation set, but using Tensorflow Object Detection API 2 and Tensorflow Model Zoo.

I have already tried the guide at this [link](https://neptune.ai/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-api-best-practices-to-training-evaluation-deployment), but this give me only performance and I need to find the best model.

At the moment, I set the fine-tuned model config like:

```
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/annotations/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/annotations/validation.record"
  }
```

and I run in parallel:

the validation script which waits for new checkpoints:

```
!python model_main_tf2.py 
  --pipeline_config_path= path to your config file 
  --model_dir= path to a directory with your model 
  --checkpoint_dir= path to a directory with checkpoints 
  --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1
```

and the training script which generates checkpoints:

```
!python model_main_tf2.py 
--model_dir= path to a directory with your model 
--pipeline_config_path= path to your config file 
--num_train_steps=13000
```

I'm working on Google Colab.

Running this code give me the checkpoints for the trained model and eval events like `./events.out.tfevents.1635340070.da52917cf102.2947.0.v2` which i can plot with tensorboard but I can't do anything else.
I think this is a kind of single split validation Keras-like but I can't find an automatic way to save best model and I can't figure it out how to extend this with multiple folds.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Is this possibile [sic]" is not a programming question. Try implementing cross validation yourself and when you get stuck with a specific issue or question, comeback here and post it using the [minimal amount of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited the question and I provided some code snippets, hoping someone will answer